# Необходимо ли использовать AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-app-compat-activity

Для чего Android Studio по умолчанию генерирует `AppCompatActivity`, когда я создаю любую активность через окно создания активностей?

На сколько я понимаю, `AppCompatActivity` используется для того, чтобы внедрить новые "плюшки" андроида в старые версии (будь то фрагменты в версии ниже 3-тей или материальный дизайн ниже 5-ой) и `ToolBar` (если я правильно понял, это тот же `ActionBar`).

Может есть еще какая-то задумка в генерации, даже если я ничего такого не использую, неспроста же она?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам не нужны все те [возможности](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), которые представлены библиотекой поддержки *AppCompat* (а их не так уж и много:`Toolbar`, виджеты в стиле Material Design и темы Material Design, в основном) вы можете не использовать `AppCompatActivity`.

При этом вы можете использовать другие библиотеки поддержки из секции v7, вроде `RecyclerView`, `CardView`, `GridLayout`, `Pallete` и пр., так как они подключаются отдельно.

Так же вы можете использовать фрагменты в версиях ниже API 10, так как они входят в библиотеку поддержки *[v4 Support](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#v4)*, *AppCompat* просто включает в себя зависимость к этой библиотеке, поэтому подключив первую не требуется отдельно подключать вторую.

Виджет `Toolbar` это очень далеко не тот же `ActionBar`, сходство только в назначении - инструмент намного гибче и "приятнее" в использовании (с точки зрения разработчика)

Comment: А с `AppCompat` нужно использовать и фрагменты с библиотеки поддержки? Я только что столкнулся с проблемой, что `backstack` обычных фрагментов не работает в `AppCompatActivity`, но работает в `Activity`.

Answer (score 4):

`AppCompatActivity` применяется для обратной совместимости в плане дизайна. Также `ActionbarActivity` с API 21 `deprecated`, чем подталкивают на использование `AppCompatActivity`. Плюс некоторые изменения "под капотом", как то использование `Toolbar` и пр.

Многие помешались на этом `Material design`, поэтому и инструмент для разработки приложений также не отстает от модных тенденций.

Answer (score 1):

На версиях ниже 5й можно подключить библиотеку RecyclerView. Подробнее по ссылке

[https://habrahabr.ru/post/237101/ ]